# python: https download multiple files and folders

Tags: python, https, download

I need a file downloader and I tried to write it but I have problems to download files over a https connection. It's easy to download files over http but for the https connection I have a username and password. I usually connect to the website with this line of code in firefox:

```
https://username:password@site.com/path
```

I want to download every single file + (sub)folder in there. How can I do this? This is how it looks like when I'm connected in firefox:

```
http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/6355/52961177.png
http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/624/55225462.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you need Python ? Using a command line tool as *curl* should to the job.
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/ is a good library for implementing HTTP clients.